# Using Regex with Find and Replace for Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio

I want to do a Find and Replace (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> <kbd>F</kbd>) through my program and replace all function declarations, like this:

```
void foo(int i) {
```

With this (a predefined macro):

```
TestStart(foo)
```

I have the Regex to capture the text down:

```
void (?<name>\w+)\(int i\) \{
```

But I need some help with the replacement.  How can I reference `name` from the above regex?  I think this is my closest attempt:

```
TestStart\(<name>\)
```

I've tried lost of combinations of `<>` or `()` or `{}` and none seem to work.  Help?

Comment: If you omit the `?<name>` part, you can just use a backreference: `TestStart\(\1\)` The `\1` part should be replaced with the name.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen sorry, whats that?

Comment: Sorry, hit enter too soon :P

Comment: @DrewMcGowen haha, take your time

Comment: I tried that too, the regex too I'm using http://regexhero.net/tester/ isn't showing it to work.  could it be wrong?  its been great for me in the past

Comment: Didn't `TestStart${name}` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using this:

```
TestStart($1)
```

Visual Studio doesn't use the `\1` as the reference to the previously captured text as suggested by others.

Comment: *Sigh* Microsoft and its infinite wisdom :P

Comment: @DrewMcGowen Haha, thank you for your help though, it pointed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, you can use the back-references to named captures in the form of

<kbd>**${**</kbd> + <kbd>***CAPTURE_GROUP_NAME***</kbd> + <kbd>**}**</kbd>

See [*Substitutions in Regular Expressions*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx):

> **`${name}`**   
>   Includes the last substring matched by the named group that is designated by `(?<name> )` in the replacement string. For more information, see [Substituting a Named Group](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0(v=vs.110).aspx#Named).

So, in your case, you search for

```
void (?<name>\w+)\(int i\) \{
```

And replace with `TestStart(${name})`.